# Adding numbers from a string that are separated by a space

Tags: java

I'm writing a program for class and what it does is it asks the user how many students are in a class and how many exams they took. Then, using a for loop, it asks for the name and exam scores of each individual student based on what you entered before, once you have entered that it gives you their average test score and a few other things. The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how you take the average of the test scores. I can't get my program to read the test scores put in by the user and then take the average. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Define Variables
        int Students;
        int Exams;
        int Sum = 0;
        int ExamAverage = 0;
        String ExamScores;
        String StudentName;



        //Create Scanner
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Print the First Block
        System.out.println("Welcome to GradeCalculator!");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of students: ");
        Students = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the number of exams: ");
        Exams = s.nextInt();
        s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");

        //For Loop
        for (int i = 1; i<=Students; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter Student " + i + "'s name: ");
            StudentName = s.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter exam scores: " );
            ExamScores = s.nextLine();
            Sum+=Integer.parseInt(ExamScores);
            ExamAverage = Sum/Exams;
            System.out.println("Grade Statistics for " + StudentName);
            System.out.println("\t Average: " + ExamAverage);
            System.out.println("\t Letter Grade: ");
            System.out.println("\t"+ StudentName + " gets a ");
            System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");
        }

        //Print the Last Block
        System.out.println("Class Statistics:");
        System.out.println("\t Average: ");
        System.out.println("\t Lowest: ");
        System.out.println("\t Highest: ");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Done, Good Bye!");


    }

}
```

Comment: First step: break the problem down. Decompose the problem into its constituent steps, and then try to solve each step one at a time.

Comment: move ExamAverage outside the loop.  Also, you are not incrementing Exams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding numbers from a string that are separated by a space :

```
String allNumbers = "12 34 67 34 56 78";
int total = 0;
for(String str : allNumbers.split("\\s")){
   total+=Integer.parseInt(str);
}
```

Comment: How do you make this work for all of the students though? For example, if you type in that there are 3 students then the program will ask you for information about three students but the average only works for the first student, it isn't running through the other two.